# $L^{p}$ boundedness of the sum of independent variables

Tags: probability-theory

I'm self-studying Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis by Muscalu and Schlag and I have unfortunately been stuck on a equivalence (maybe trivial?) statement about the $ L^{p} $ boundedness of the sum of independent variables. I attached a picture of this statement (right at the start of the proof).

[Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1A1n.png)

I'm stuck because I am unable to prove the boundedness of $ (\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} |X_{j}|^{2} )^{\frac{1}{2}} $ non-trivially. I have tried expanding the whole sum using the Newton multinomial formula but this does not seem to agree with the term "simple" used before.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Suppose $\sum_{j=1}^nX_j\in L^p$. Let $j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$. By independence, $\mathbb E[\vert\sum_{j=1}^nX_j\vert^p]=\mathbb E[\vert\varphi((X_i)_{i\neq j})\vert]<+\infty$, where $\varphi((x_i)_{i\neq j})=\mathbb E[\vert X_j+\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^nx_i\vert^p]$. As $\varphi((X_i)_{i\neq j})\in L^1$, it is almost surely finite, hence there exists $(x_i)_{i\neq j}$ such that $\varphi((x_i)_{i\neq j})<+\infty$, which proves that $X_j\in L^p$.
- Suppose that $X_j\in L^p$ for all $j$. Equivalently, $\vert X_j\vert^2\in L^{p/2}$ for all $j$, so the sum $\sum_{j=1}^n\vert X_j\vert^2\in L^{p/2}$. Equivalently, $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\vert X_j\vert^2\right)^{1/2}\in L^p$.
- Suppose that $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\vert X_j\vert^2\right)^{1/2}\in L^p$. By Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, we have that
  $$
  \vert\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\vert\le\sum_{j=1}^n\vert X_j\vert\le \left(n\sum_{j=1}^n\vert X_j\vert^2\right)^{1/2}\in L^p.
  $$

Comment: Thank you this solution. About the first point, may I ask why the function $\varphi((X_{i})_{i \neq j})$ is $L^{1}$? Is it because it is chosen to be a polynomial function of the $X_{i}$?

Comment: Because $\mathbb E[\vert\sum_{j=1}^nX_j\vert^p]=\mathbb E[\vert\varphi((X_i)_{i\neq j})\vert]$ and $\sum_{j=1}^nX_j\in L^1$ by assumption.
The property I used is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then for any nonnegative measurable map $f$, $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)]=\mathbb E[\varphi(X)]$, where $\varphi$ is defined by $\varphi:x\mapsto\mathbb E[f(x,Y)]$. Then $f(X,Y)\in L^1\iff\varphi(X)\in L^1$.